# Slow database query: Using VB.net connecting to Access

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which will only allow a certain amount of concurrent users to use the program at one time. To do this I have a single table in an access database which holds each user that is using the program. Now although this does work the query seems to be running very slowly, I am certain it is something to do with the database functions as it was running fine before I implemented them.

Here are my functions:

```
Public Function openDB() As Boolean
    cnn.Open()
    Return True
End Function

Public Function closeDB() As Boolean
    cnn.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```

Then there is the function for checking the database. This is where I think it may be tripping up because I have 2 queries running here:

```
Public Function CheckLicence() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = HandleRegistry()
    If result = True Then
        Dim _table As String = "Users"
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & _table & " WHERE Machine_ID='" & CpuId() & "'"
        Dim sizeQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & _table
        Dim NoUsers As Integer = 0
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


        Dim sizeCdm As New OleDbCommand(sizeQuery, cnn)
        NoUsers = sizeCdm.ExecuteScalar()

        If dr.Read() Then
            Return True
        Else
            If NoUsers < My.Settings.NoUsers Then

                addToDB()
            Else
                MsgBox("Too many users are currently using this program. Clear a user and try again.")

                Return False
            End If
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Your licence has expired, contact support to purchase a new licence.")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

And to add and remove I have to get the cpu id, I found the code for that on here somewhere it does work but maybe that could be the slow part, I dont actually know if this is the correct way of getting it.

```
 Public Sub addToDB()
    Dim _table As String = "Users"
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO " & _table & " ([User], [Machine_ID]) VALUES (?,?)"
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Environment.UserName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CpuId())
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


End Sub
Public Sub RemoveFromDB()
    Dim _table As String = "Users"

    Dim query As String = "DELETE * FROM " & _table & " WHERE Machine_ID='" & CpuId() & "'"
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
Private Function CpuId() As String
    Dim computer As String = "."
    Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:" &
        "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &
        computer & "\root\cimv2")
    Dim processors As Object = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from " &
        "Win32_Processor")

    Dim cpu_ids As String = ""
    For Each cpu As Object In processors
        cpu_ids = cpu_ids & ", " & cpu.ProcessorId
    Next cpu
    If cpu_ids.Length > 0 Then cpu_ids =
        cpu_ids.Substring(2)

    Return cpu_ids
End Function
```

Comment: How slow is slow? Is it actually hanging on something or just taking longer than you'd expect?

Comment: On my machine its really just the case of 5 seconds but when tested on a non-development machine its almost 30 seconds which will be very annoying for the end user because this check is made every time they go to use a function of the program. I think it should be almost instant because its not really checking much data its just the one table.

Comment: How about storing the cpuID globally and fetching only once. Also, use the Using construct on anything that needs to be disposed. Lastly, run a few StopWatches around your methods to see which one is slow or just debug through each one to find the slow method.

Comment: Just set the cpuID on the startup and now it is much faster, still a small bit of lag but I think that will be fine now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the cpuID globally and fetching only once. Also, use the Using construct on anything that needs to be disposed. Lastly, run a few StopWatches around your methods to see which one is slow or just debug through each one to find the slow method.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> How about storing the cpuID globally and fetching only once. Also, use the Using >construct on anything that needs to be disposed. Lastly, run a few StopWatches >around your methods to see which one is slow or just debug through each one to >find the slow method. – [Andrew Mortimer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358543/andrew-mortimer/)

Moved the call for getting the cpuID to the program initialisation so that it runs on startup. This made it run much faster than it did before.